# Webstorm throws no error, Typescript does

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, global

```
declare var _isEnvironment : (environment : string) => boolean;


_isEnvironment = function(environment : string) : boolean {
    return process.argv[2] === '--' + environment;
}
```

I'm trying to create a global function accessible in every .ts file - instead of a static approach, I figured I'd extend the global scope. Hence the declare var. I tried it with a d.ts file; no effect, it still pukes out the same error.

I do not understand how webstorm allows this, whilst Typescript cries on compilation.

```
App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: _isEnvironment is not defined
```

i'm slowly getting sick of typescript, it makes simples things so unnecessarily complex.................

edit:
seems like something is off with the compilation from .ts to .js?

the js in dist looks like this:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var electron_1 = require("electron");
var path = require("path");
var EmitListenerHandler_1 = require("./listeners/EmitListenerHandler");
var LoginRequest_1 = require("./net/request/impl/LoginRequest");
var Paths_1 = require("./Paths");
_isEnvironment = function (environment) {
    return process.argv[2] === '--' + environment;
};
```

I've quite noticed that there really is no _isEnvironment prior to the assignment.

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDirs": ["dist/"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "listFiles": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The above should work properly. Is this the only code?

Comment: It doesnt !!! Even copy pasting modular approaches on the typescript docs; it simply doesn't work - that's what causes me headache for over 2 days..

and yes! that's the only code, beside a console.log(_isEnvironment('dev')) within the same class

the error triggers at the assignment though, so on the _isEnvironment = func[...]

Comment: Do you need this `declare` approach or would `globalThis._foobar = ()=>'bar'` in your mainscript be viable too? Since there is a `declare` keyword in typescript too, it may be misunderstood by typescript and therefore not compiled the way you think? As it is used to declare types - that are dev only, it makes sense that it is removed while compiling.

Comment: not anymore, i decided to just go static. seems like its far more effort than documented